# How to Create sencha touch app in window phone 8?

Tags: extjs, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch

I want to make native window phone 8 build from sencha touch. I have also tried phonegap but no succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is, create your project/app using Sencha Touch and wrap it up using PhoneGap/Cordova. Please follow the below links to gain some insights on how to use PhoneGap to build Windows app.

http://www.sencha.com/learn/getting-started-with-sencha-touch-2

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975345.aspx

Good Luck!

Comment: :(  I have used phonegap plugin in window phone. It did not work when I used sencha plugin. please send me link of working example.

Comment: http://robertdougan.com/posts/packaging-sencha-touch-2-with-phonegap-cordova --> You can give it a try..

Comment: Also, once you create your Sencha Touch app, you can just drop the files that were created using Sencha Touch into the WWW folder of your PhoneGap project. From there, you can create a build for your Windows app