# Sencha touch packaging for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sencha-touch

I created a sencha touch app using sencha cmd and I was trying to test it on windows phone 8 emulator. I have read that we should integrate sencha touch with phonegap to build it to windows phone 8. So can anyone help me with the process of how to integrate those two or wrap the sencha code with phonegap ?? any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109570/how-to-create-sencha-touch-app-in-window-phone-8

Comment: @Geniewanted - Thank you!! compiling was successful but i am getting an error related to build.js while installing the app on emulator. any hints ??